# protractor not connecting to chrome

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am using protractor@3.2.2. It was working fine with chrome all these days. But all of a sudden it is not able to connect to chrome(chromeDriver).

It says

> SessionNotCreatedError: session not created exception

It is able to connect to Firefox and Edge.

I am using chromeDriver@2.21

Any ideas about how to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like a webdriver error.  I'd either upgrade or downgrade your chrome driver version

Comment: This happens because the previous session wasn't shutdown properly and it happens when there is exception thrown in your test.
Could you post your cofig file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chromeDriver 2.21 supports till chrome version 53, But i was using chrome version 54. This is the reason why the chromeDriver is not able to connect to chrome.
Once i downgrade to chrome version 53, everything started to work as expected.

So if you guys face the same issue, check your chromeDriver version and your chrome version.